Any resources or way I can search things about integrals without the theorem of calculus
I have so much maths to learn in such a short time and I just can't try to watch another video where all they say is 'well let's think about the antiderivative!' I dont like that to do anything with integrals it's always just 'well this would be the derivative so let's do the opposite' I just need something for integrals alone. It's like trying to understand how to write the square root as an indice and having an annoying bird in my ear telling me to think about $x^2$ first because that's the opposite.Thanks.

Is your question the question in the title?

Yeah (11 more characters to go)

Have you learned the fundamental theorem of calculus? It's very useful for basic functions and a very simple method.

Apostol teaches integrals before derivatives. Try his approach.

Here’s how I think of it. If you have a function $f(x)$, then its derivative $f’(x)$ tells you the rate of change of $f(x)$ at any point. But when we deal with antiderivatives, we need to think “If $f(x)$ IS the rate of change of another function $F(x)$, then how would $F(x)$ change over time?”. And with the integral, we are just asking for the net change of $F(x)$ over a certain x-interval.

To begin calculating simpler integrals explicitly, I don't think there are any other ways than to think of them as antiderivatives; if instead to see in the abstract what integration is, there are various calculus textbooks that begin with the approach of partitions etc.
I can recommend a good book, Calculus Volume 1 by Gilbert Strang, certainly there will be better books but it has a simple if theoretical and formal approach.(I have studied these topics in non-English books, someone could definitely make better suggestions)
